# Not able to display parquet file output using Spark

Tags: scala, apache-spark, parquet

Installed Spark on local (on Linux file system with no HADOOP), Everything seems to be working fine except reading parquet file and displaying results on console. After reading parquet file, when I do `dataframe.show()` it just  this Indefinnitely:

`[Stage 4:>                       (0 + 1) / 1]`

Not sure if I need to configure anything specific on local installation?

Can some one please help me on this?

Installed spark on local(on Linux) and followed below steps using  spark/scala:

```
scala> val columns = Seq("firstname","middlename","lastname","dob","gender","salary")
val columns: Seq[String] = List(firstname, middlename, lastname, dob, gender, salary)

scala> val data = Seq(("James ","x","Smith","36636","M",3000),
     |       ("Michael ","Rose","cc","40288","M",4000),
     |       ("Robert ","c","Williams","42114","M",4000),
     |       ("Maria ","Anne","Jones","39192","F",4000),
     |       ("Jen","Mary","Brown","34552","F",-1)
     |     )
     |
val data: Seq[(String, String, String, String, String, Int)] = List(("James ",x,Smith,36636,M,3000), ("Michael ",Rose,cc,40288,M,4000), ("Robert ",c,Williams,42114,M,4000), ("Maria ",Anne,Jones,39192,F,4000), (Jen,Mary,Brown,34552,F,-1))

scala> val df1 = data.toDF(columns:_*)
val df1: org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame = [firstname: string, middlename: string ... 4 more fields]

scala> df1.show()
+---------+----------+--------+-----+------+------+
|firstname|middlename|lastname|  dob|gender|salary|
+---------+----------+--------+-----+------+------+
|   James |         x|   Smith|36636|     M|  3000|
| Michael |      Rose|      cc|40288|     M|  4000|
|  Robert |         c|Williams|42114|     M|  4000|
|   Maria |      Anne|   Jones|39192|     F|  4000|
|      Jen|      Mary|   Brown|34552|     F|    -1|
+---------+----------+--------+-----+------+------+

scala> df1.printSchema()
root
 |-- firstname: string (nullable = true)
 |-- middlename: string (nullable = true)
 |-- lastname: string (nullable = true)
 |-- dob: string (nullable = true)
 |-- gender: string (nullable = true)
 |-- salary: integer (nullable = false)


scala> df1.write.partitionBy("gender","salary").parquet("/home/usalla/spark_test/emppq.parquet")

scala> val parqDF2 = spark.read.parquet("/home/usalla/spark_test/emppq.parquet")
val parqDF2: org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame = [firstname: string, middlename: string ... 4 more fields]

scala> parqDF2.createOrReplaceTempView("ParquetTable2")

scala> val df3 = spark.sql("select * from ParquetTable2  where gender='M' and salary >= 4000")
val df3: org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame = [firstname: string, middlename: string ... 4 more fields]

scala> df3.explain
warning: 1 deprecation (since 2.13.3); for details, enable `:setting -deprecation` or `:replay -deprecation`
== Physical Plan ==
*(1) ColumnarToRow
+- FileScan parquet [firstname#144,middlename#145,lastname#146,dob#147,gender#148,salary#149] Batched: true, DataFilters: [], Format: Parquet, Location: InMemoryFileIndex(1 paths)[file:/home/usalla/spark_test/emppq.parquet], PartitionFilters: [isnotnull(gender#148), isnotnull(salary#149), (gender#148 = M), (salary#149 >= 4000)], PushedFilters: [], ReadSchema: struct<firstname:string,middlename:string,lastname:string,dob:string>
scala> df3.printSchema()
root
 |-- firstname: string (nullable = true)
 |-- middlename: string (nullable = true)
 |-- lastname: string (nullable = true)
 |-- dob: string (nullable = true)
 |-- gender: string (nullable = true)
 |-- salary: integer (nullable = true)


scala> df3.show()
[Stage 4:>                                                          (0 + 1) / 1]
^Z
```

Comment: Showing `[Stage 4:> (0 + 1) / 1]` indefinitely hints at the fact that your tasks do not get broadcasted to any executor. That code bit you shared seems to hint that you were in a REPL of some sorts. Did you kick off a `spark-shell`? Or were you just simply running the vanilla scala REPL?

Comment: Thank you for your response, I did kick-off spark-shell and running it through spark-shell. I am able to read/write text/csv/json files and display results, but not successful with parquet format.

Comment: Which version of Spark are you running? Also, do you have any specific configurations you're starting your `spark-shell` command with?

Comment: I am using Spark 3.3.1, spark-defaults.conf has following: # Enable to store the event log
spark.eventLog.enabled true

#Location where to store event log
spark.eventLog.dir file:///tmp/spark-events

#Location from where history server to read event log
spark.history.fs.logDirectory file:///tmp/spark-events
spark.speculation false  and I am starting spark shell without any specific configurations, Today When I tried to read/write the data into ORC format it worked fine and it showed the results too. Looks like there is some issue with parquet format read/write?